# What is wrong with my code PHP/mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just got assignment to make html form with php that will store information in mysql database. It is not making table and I can't figure out why. Here is html code(btw I dont care about sql injection becouse this is just for school)

```
<?php


@$ime = $_POST['ime'];
@$prezime = $_POST['prezime'];
@$email = $_POST['email'];
@$adresa = $_POST['adresa'];
@$misljenje = $_POST['misljenje'];


$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_query($conn,"create database baza_podataka");
mysqli_select_db($conn,"baza_podataka");
mysqli_query($conn,"create table 'podatci' (id int primary key auto_increment, ime varchar(10), prezime varchar(10), email varchar(20), adresa varchar(20), misljenje varchar(100))");
mysqli_query($conn,"INSTERT INTO `podatci` VALUES ('$ime','$prezime','$email','$adresa','$misljenje')");
```

?>

and html

```
<form name="forma" action="obrada.php" method="post">
            <label>Ime :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="ime" size="20"/><br><br>

            <label>Prezime :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="prezime" size="20"/><br><br>

            <label>E-mail :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" size="20"/><br><br>

            <label>Adresa :</label>
                    <input type="text" id="adresa" size="40"/><br><br>

            <label>Vase misljenje :</label><br><br>
                    <textarea name="misljenje" id="misljenje"></textarea>

            </label><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: "btw I dont care about sql injection becouse this is just for school" You should always care about writing secure code. It's easy to get in the habit of writing bad code.

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of problems..

- Remove the error suppression operator. `@$ime = $_POST['ime'];` Remove the `@` from all the variables.
- You are creating the database each and every time whenever this script is called. [**which is totally wrong**]
- It is `INSERT` not `INSTERT` on your query.
- You are passing the `$_POST` parameters directly onto your query which makes you 100% vulnerable to SQL Injection. Switch to Prepared Statements to overcome this.

Comment: when I remove @, I get Notice: Undefined index: ime in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/obrada.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: prezime in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/obrada.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: email in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/obrada.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: adresa in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/obrada.php on line 7

and It's still not creating table?

Comment: Add the name attribute on your form like this for all of your variables.. `<input type="text" name='ime' id="ime" size="20"/><br><br>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't see a `</form>` on your HTML code.

Try using `$_REQUEST['htmlvariablename'];`

```
ime = $_REQUEST['ime'];
$prezime = $_REQUEST['prezime'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$adresa = $_REQUEST['adresa'];
$misljenje = $_REQUEST['misljenje'];
```

...And as stated earlier you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

1) Use `INSERT` instead of `INSTERT`

```
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `podatci` VALUES ('$ime','$prezime','$email','$adresa','$misljenje')");
```

2) Escape all of your data using `mysqli_real_escape_string`

3) Never use error suppressor on your code `@`, instead use isset() to check if it is set or not.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$ime = isset($_POST['ime']) : mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ime']) ? '';
$prezime = isset($_POST['prezime']) : mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['prezime']) ? '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) : mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']) ? '';
$adresa = isset($_POST['adresa']) : mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['adresa']) ? '';
$misljenje = isset($_POST['misljenje']) : mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['misljenje']) ? '';
```

4) Finally, there is no need to create the database and/or table every load, you should only do it once.